# Finite Unions of Equinumerous Sets

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is the following statement provable in ZF?

Assume that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are two infinite sets. If $A_1$ is equinumerous with $B_1$ and $A_2$ is equinumerous with $B_2$, then $A_1 \cup A_2$ is equinumerous with $B_1 \cup B_2$.

Comment: The statement is false. There is a counterexample where $A_1,B_1,A_2,B_2$ are all one-element sets.

Comment: You need that the sets $A_1, A_2$ are disjoint, same for $B_1, B_2$. Then it is true and provable in ZF

Comment: @bof Good point. Let's assume one of them is infinite.

Comment: You should be able to prove this is false using amorphous sets (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set)

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it's true if you also assume that $A_1\cap A_2$ is equinumerous with $B_1\cap B_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the union is disjoint, this is easy, since the union of the bijections is itself a bijection.

If not, then this is easy to see that if we assume that $|A_1\cup A_2|=|B_1\cup B_2|$, for any two pairs as in your assumption, then taking $A_1=A_2$ and $B_1=A_1\times\{0\}$ and $B_2=A_1\times\{1\}$, we get that $|A_1|=|A_1\times 2|=|A_1|+|A_1|$.

This does not follow from $\sf ZF$, for example, if there are infinite Dedekind-finite sets that is easy, and even if we assume $\sf DC$ or its uncountable versions, there can still be counterexamples to this principle, e.g. sets which are $\aleph_1$-amorphous may exist even if we assume $\sf DC$.

On the other hand, assuming $|A|=|A\times 2|$ for any infinite set $A$, we get that $|A_1\cup A_2|=|A_1\times\{0\}\cup A_2\times\{1\}|$, since we have:

$$|A_1\cup A_2|=|(A_1\cup A_2)\times 2|\geq|A_1\times\{0\}\cup A_2\times\{1\}|\geq|A_1\cup A_2|.$$

Which means that every union can be replaced by a disjoint union, and therefore the equality ensues. Finally, Sageev proved that $|A|=|A\times 2|$ for all infinite $A$ does not imply the axiom of choice, indeed, not even the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: If $|A_1|=|B_1|$ and $|A_2|=|B_2|$ and $|A_1\cap A_2|=|B_1\cap B_2|$ does it follow (in ZF) that $|A_1\cup A_2|=|B_1\cup B_2|$? If $|A_1|\le|B_1|$ and $|A_2|\le|B_2|$ and $|B_1\cap B_2|\le|A_1\cap A_2|$ does it follow that $|A_1\cup A_2|\le|B_1\cup B_2|$?

Comment: Those are good questions. I'm not sure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Can you say more about why ℵ1-amprhous sets will be counterexamples to the principle stated in the question?

Comment: @user123: It cannot be split into two uncountable sets, and the union of two $\aleph_1$-amorphous sets (equipotent or not) can be split into two uncountable sets. So it has to be strictly larger.